# Axios vs context.spHttpClient: when to use which in SPFX http requests?

Tags: reactjs, api, sharepoint, axios, spfx

I just have a question regarding making HTTP requests from SharePoint Framework (SPFx) webparts within a SharePoint site. I've just recently started using the framework, together with a React template, for a client's app from our organisation.

Besides the built-in *fetch*, the 2 other common tools to use are the built-in *context.spHttpClient* as well as *axios*. Question is, when does use which? My assumption is to leave *context.spHttpClient* for SharePoint-related requests only, and use *axios* for external or any other requests.

Is my assumption correct? Does it have any shortcomings? If so, what is a better approach?